# Cypress: An uncaught error was detected outside of a test

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, cypress, inertiajs

Totally puzzled here. I'm trying to run E2E Cypress (v12.17.2) tests with a Laravel+Vue3 app that I've migrated to Inertia+Vite. I started with the simplest of tests, but keep running into a Cypress error:

```
An uncaught error was detected outside of a testfailed

        No commands were issued in this test.

TypeError
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress. It was caused by an unhandled promise rejection.

  > h2 is null

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
View stack trace
```

The test is a simple one that I've run many times with previous versions of this app. I don't understand this error. I've tried other simple tests as well, but keep getting the same error. Here is the code for this one test:

```js
describe('Login Flow for Registered User', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    Cypress.config('baseUrl', 'http://myapp-editor.test/')
    cy.exec('php artisan db:seed --env=testing')
  })

  it.only('Logs in a user', function () {
    cy.visit('/')

    cy.get('[data-cy=login]').click()

    cy.url().should('include', '/auth/users')

    cy.contains('Welcome')

    cy.contains('Your Profile')
  })
```

I've tried other simple tests as well, but keep getting the same error. Here is my `cypress.config.ts` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
import vitePreprocessor from 'cypress-vite'

export default defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  component: {
    supportFile: false,
    devServer: {
      framework: 'vue',
      bundler: 'vite',
    },
  },
  e2e: {
    // setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    //   // bind to the event we care about
    //   on('<event>', (arg1, arg2) => {
    //     // plugin stuff here
    //   })
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      on('file:preprocessor', vitePreprocessor())
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://wisconsin-idea.test/',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.js',
  }
})
```